# Complexity of class finding selection of entries in matrix

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-classes, matrices

Suppose I have a matrix with entries either $x$ or $y$, where the number of rows = number of columns = $n$. If I want to select/circle $n$ entries such that for each row, only exactly one is circled, for each column, also exactly one is circled, and such that all entries circled are only $x$ (if such a circling of entries exists), what complexity class does this belong to? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be the set of rows in the given matrix and $V$ the set of columns. For each $x$ at row $i$ and column $j$, add an edge between row $i$ and column $j$. You will have an [(unweighted) bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) $G=(U,V, E)$. The problem is to find a [perfect matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)), which is basically the same as find the maximum matching of $G$.

There are various [algorithms that compute the maximum cardinality matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching#Algorithms_for_bipartite_graphs). For example, [The Hopcroft–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) runs in $O(\max(|E|\sqrt {|V|}, |V|^2)$.

So, we can say that the complexity class of the problem in the question is in $O(n^{2.5})$ since $|E|\le n^2$ and $|V|= 2n$.